# When do we use "->" in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Sometimes I do see

```
self->someData = d;
```

in Objective-C code.  Can someone explain when that is used?

Comment: You can try find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c

Comment: ah, if searching for "arrow operator", then easier... on iBooks or Preview on Mac I can't search for `->`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access a variable of an instance which isn't listed as a property.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax can be used to directly access public instance variables of an object. (It does not work for private variables.) You probably should create a property and use that instead, or use key value coding.

Comment: and is it true that within the class, this notation can access the private and protected instance variables?  It seems that some people also use `self->someData` instead of just `someData` to signal to himself that this is an instance variable within any instance methods

Comment: It does work for private instance variables.  `someOtherObject->privateIVar` probably won't work, but it will always work if the left hand side is `self`.