# Updating contents of class variable NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I'm new to Objective C and iOS development in general, so if I missed some information that needs to be included please let me know and I'll do my best. At the same time, if any of my assumptions are incorrect or if I set this up totally dumb, please don't hesitate to yell at me. Thanks!

I have a class object called `feeds`. Here's how I initialize it in the .h file:

```
@interface ClassViewController : ContentViewController <UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* feeds;
```

and in the .m:

```
@dynamic feeds;
```

I'm trying to get results from JSON and load them up into the `feeds`. Let's assume that `resArr` has correct data in it:

```
NSArray *resArr = [results objectForKey:@"data"];

if([self->feeds count]) {
    [self->feeds removeAllObjects];
    [self->feeds addObjectsFromArray:resArr];
 }
 else {
     self->feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:resArr];
 }
```

Now, this works fine the first time (i.e., the first time I put data into the array), but I get the following error subsequent times: ***** -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray**

I'm clueless. Any ideas?

*Edit: JSON structures*

1:

```
{"code":200,"data":[{"name":"ABM"},{"name":"ACC"}]}
```

2:

```
{"code":200,"data":{"100":{"subject":"ABM","title":"Decision Making in Agri-Food"},"130":{"subject":"ABM","title":"Farm Management I"}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use self.feeds instead of self->feeds, here's a good read [Dot (“.”) operator and arrow (“->”) operator use in C vs. Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c)

are you sure the subsequent times are actually NSArrays?

*edit additon*

Looks like the first JSon is just a array of names, where's as the second is a dictionary keyed with 100, 200, etc. So the JSON converts this into a dictionary keyed to 100, 200, ...

```
NSArray* resArr = [results objectForKey:@"data"];

if([self.feeds count]) {
    [self.feeds removeAllObjects];
    if([resArr isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
       [self.feeds addObjectsFromArray:resArr.allValues];
    else
       [self.feeds addObjectsFromArray:resArr];
 }
 else {
     self.feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:resArr];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the literature. I'm positive that `resArr` is being populated correctly. I'm not sure how to `NSLog` an array, but I am `NSLog`ging the JSON string, and it is exactly the same format as the first result which is being inserted into the array correctly.

Comment: you can nslog the type/contents of it

`type NSLog(@"Class: %@ Conents: %@", [resArr class], resArr);`

Comment: Odd. The first result was of type `JKArray`, the second of type `JKDictionary`. Let me append the structures of the returned JSON and perhaps the issue lies there.

Comment: Looks like the first JSon is just a array of names, where's as the second is a dictionary keyed with 100, 200, etc. So the JSON converts this into a dictionary keyed to 100, 200, ...

Comment: Okay, thanks. If you wouldn't mind could you please let me know how I might translate that into type `NSArray` given that structure? I know it's outside the scope of the question but it would help immensely.

Comment: if you can test if its a dictioanry then add the values from the dictionary.. `if([resArr isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]) [self.feeds addObjectsFromArray:resArr.allValues]`

keep in mind. the AllValues will lose the keys associated with the values.