# What is the significance of -> in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dot (“.”) operator and arrow (“->”) operator use in C vs. Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c)

How different is the use of -> in Objective C compared to C.

Comment: [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

It has an additional meaning, although the actual implementation of that meaning is not different from the C use case. In Objective-C, not only members of struct pointers can be accessed usig this operator, but instance variables too. However, since the Objective-C runtime is implemented in C, objects are just struct pointers, and ivar manipulation is just structure field manipulation.