# Objective-c -> Structure Operator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, cocoa

While reading some tutorials i found for the first time the "structure operator", I read that it's used to refer of an instace variable.

```
-(void)setNumber:(int)n{
   self.number = n;
}

-(void)setNumber:(int)n{
   self->number = n;
}
```

My doubt is: what it doing exactely? When do i use it? Why should i prefer it to the dot notation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c

Comment: Keep in mind that Objective-C is built on top of C, and all the C syntax "shows through".  Basically, the C semantics for `->` was carried over into Objective-C unchanged, while additional semantics were overloaded onto `.`, vs what that token means in C.  (And you need to have at least a basic understanding of C before you attempt to learn/use Objective-C.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dot syntax in Objective-C is just syntactic sugar which is replaced by the compiler with a method invocation. `->` dereferences the pointer and accesses the member directly, with no method invocation.

In an Objective-C method call, you don't need to say `self->foo`, if your class has an instance variable named `foo` the compiler will infer the `self->` portion of it. Because of this, while it's not completely unheard of, uses of `->` with an Objective-C object are comparatively rare.

Comment: Why didn't they just remove this kind of syntax? it can only cause trubles

Comment: There are still legitimate uses (direct access of instance variables of non-self instances -- useful when implementing NSCopying, for instance), not to mention that `->` still has plenty of legitimate uses in C, of which Objective-C is a strict superset.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow `->` operator accesses instance variables directly, **which you don't want in general,** since it violates encapsulation and circumvents accessor methods (that can be a potential source of problems, like KVO not working or some desired side effects not taking place).

Instead, you should almost always use `.`, because it accesses the properties using getters and setters.

Comment: Why didn't they just remove this kind of syntax? it can only cause trubles

Comment: The OP posted an example of an accessor method implementation. In those it's proper and common to access the ivar directly.

Comment: @TimDoll There are situations where the arrow notation is needed and makes sense. Also, Objective-C, being a strict superset of C, cannot remove C features.

Comment: Can you please make me an example of when it would be needed?

Comment: @TimDoll See ipmcc's comment about NSCopying. Implementing `isEqual:` or `compare:` are similar cases.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe the arrow operator isn't necessary even in an accessor method. Inside any instance method, ivars are accessible without referencing them as `self->ivar`. Also, this answer is technically correct, so your downvote is invalid.

Comment: @H2CO3 The arrow operator is perfectly valid to use in an accessor, as everywhere else.