# Why is my UILabel getting deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie, cfstring

Im trying to track down the source of a crash. I've profiled the app to look for zombies and it appears to be related to updating the text in one of my UILabels. I don't think I am setting the text value improperly. Does this look right?

[image]

This is where I'm setting the text of the UILabels.

```
- (void) updateTimecodeDisplay
{
    VarController *sharedController = [VarController sharedController];

    int time0 = sharedController.timeCode0Property;
    int time1 = sharedController.timeCode1Property;
    int time2 = sharedController.timeCode2Property;
    int time3 = sharedController.timeCode3Property;
    int time4 = sharedController.timeCode4Property;
    int time5 = sharedController.timeCode5Property;
    int time6 = sharedController.timeCode6Property;
    int time7 = sharedController.timeCode7Property;
    int time8 = sharedController.timeCode8Property;
    int time9 = sharedController.timeCode9Property;


    if (time0 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel0 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time0]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel0 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time1 != 16)
    {
       [timeCodeLabel1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time1]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time2 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time2]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time3 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time3]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time4 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel4 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time4]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel4 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time5 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel5 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time5]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel5 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time6 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel6 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time6]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel6 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time7 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel7 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time7]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel7 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    } 
    if (time8 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel8 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time8]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel8 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
    if (time9 != 16)
    {
        [timeCodeLabel9 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time9]];
    }
    else {
        [timeCodeLabel9 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
}
```

The UILabels are being declared in the header file like this:

I've now added properties for the UILabels as hinted at below, and synthesized them in the .m file. Still getting the exact same issue though.

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel0;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel1;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel2;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel3;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel4;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel5;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel6;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel7;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel8;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeCodeLabel9;
```

Comment: In the stack trace on the right, can you see which line in updateTimecodeDisplay it's being triggered on?  Is updateTimecodeDisplay being called when the view is not rendered on the screen?

Comment: You've declared the UILabel's globally, not as the properties of a view controller?

Comment: Please stop vandalising your own question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out this post to talk about the "->" operator:[Dot (".") operator and arrow ("->") operator use in C vs. Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c)

It means that you are not supposed to use "->" to access property. Because there are many underlying layer. Hope this helps.

IBOutlet should be using `@weak`

Comment: Can you post how you declare all your UILabel? More info could be helpful.

Comment: Profile said it's zombie. That might have other places that caused this problem which the problem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: IBOutlet should be used weak. Otherwise, it will have retain cycles.

Comment: The way you are referencing the UILabel is weird also. You can either access dot notation or instant variable. But you just referenced it by name. I think you might have other issues. Can you just try to debug it instead of running the Profile? I don't think you need to do that.