# Replace NAN value in order to avoid Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, highcharts, nan, pie-chart

I am drawing pie-charts using HighChart Library ([Pie-chart](https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/pie-basic)).
 While Passing data to chart my code is like this :

```
 pie.data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@{
                                                      @"name": @"New Jersey",
                                                      @"y": self->numPlusNJ
                                                      },
                    @{
                      @"name": @"Miami FLG",
                      @"y": self->numPlusMiamiFLG
                      },
                    @{
                      @"name": @"Chicago",
                      @"y": self->numPlusChicago
                      },nil];
```

where the values like self->numPlusNJ are NSNumbers.
Sometimes after calculations value like 0(zero) comes in NSNumbers and it is taking those values as NAN.
In those cases I am getting this error while drawing pie-chart :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid number value (NaN) in JSON write'.
```

I tried to Replace NAN value by 0 like this :

```
if(isnan([self->numRPercentNJ doubleValue])){self->numRPercentNJ = 0;}
```

But in that case I am getting can't insert nil in dictionary object.

So, Currently I am unsure about how to replace this NAN value by something in order to avoid crash.

Comment: try with `null` instead of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your numbers (`numPlusMiamiFLG`, etc.) are properties on your current class, I'd suggest implementing an accessor for each one:

```
- (NSNumber *)numPlusMiamiFLG
{
    // Check if NaN
    if ([[NSDecimalNumber notANumber] isEqualToNumber: _numPlusMiamiFLG] {
        return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0]; // Or whatever default
    } else {
        return _numPlusMiamiFLG;
    }
}
```

There's a chance you are not initializing your numbers correctly if you are getting `nil`/`NaN`. So I would double-check them.

Also note that the `->` is not supposed to be used on Objective-C classes. [As seen in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072688/dot-operator-and-arrow-operator-use-in-c-vs-objective-c).