# Iterator de-reference then "." operator versus. "->" operator

Tags: c++, listiterator

I've been given some C++ code that has a list/iterator of the following struct.

```
typedef struct{
  int x;
  int y;
}my_struct;

std::list<my_struct> the_list;
std::list<my_struct>::iterator the_iter = the_list.begin();
```

The code then accesses x and y of `the_iter` this way:

```
(*the_iter).x;
(*the_iter).y;
```

I want to change these to the more readable version:

```
the_iter->x;
the_iter->y;
```

From my C perspective, this is totally fine for pointer dereferencing.  Is this also the case for iterators?  Is there any reason why my colleague would use `(*pointer).` instead of `p->`

Comment: They may not have known about it? As you say they do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Ask your colleague.

Answer (score 6):

Considering the general case, it could happen that some iterator class did not provide `operator ->`, and doing `(*it).x` would be the only possible way. Another possibility is that `operator *` and `operator ->` have some non-standard semantics and are not interchangeble. However, this class would fail to satisfy any iterator concept, and, technically, would not be an iterator.

In your case it is `std::list<T>::iterator`, for which `it->x` and `(*it).x` are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

This answer has background on why the two methods both exist for pointers if they achieve the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6632474/3113508

Your change would be perfectly fine (and probably preferred by most) for  STL iterators for the same reason the `->` operator is generally preferred for use with pointers.

However, be aware that the unary `*` operator and the `->`operator can be overloaded to provide semantically different behavior in user-defined classes. So, potentially someone could choose to use `*` or `->` in a different way, such that `foo->bar` is no longer the same as `(*foo).bar`. Make sure you are familiar with the documentation for the classes that you are using.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not consider looking into operator overloading.

Answer (score 2):

No, style preferences / knowledge of `->` would be the only reason they would use `(* a).` vs `->`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `operator->` can be overloaded to return multiple levels of proxy objects with overloaded `operator->` to which it is then again applied recursively, until a plain pointer is returned, like in [Wrapping C++ Member Function Calls by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf).

Whereas `operator.` cannot be overloaded in C++.

The example from that paper is:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void prefix() { cout<< "prefix"; }
void suffix() { cout<< " suffix\n"; }

template<class T>
class Call_proxy{
  T* p;
public:
  Call_proxy(T* pp) :p(pp){ }
  ˜Call_proxy() { suffix() ; }
  T* operator->() { return p; }
};

template<class T>
class Wrap{
  T* p;
public:
  Wrap(T* pp) :p(pp) { }
  Call_proxy<T> operator->() { prefix() ; return Call_proxy<T>(p) ; }
};

class X{ // one user class
public:
X() { cout<< "make an X\n"; }
  int f() const{ cout<< "f()"; return 1; }
  void g() const{ cout<< "g()"; }
};

class Y{ // another user class
public:
  Y() { cout<< "make a Y\n"; }
  void h() const{ cout<< "h()"; }
};

int main() // simple test code
{
  Wrap<X> xx(new X) ;
  Wrap<Y> yy(new Y) ;
  if(xx->f()) cout<< "done\n";
  xx->g() ;
  yy->h() ;
  return 0;
}
```

Each call of `xx` and `yy` is bracketed by a pair of prefix()/suffix() calls, so the program produced:

```
make an X
make a Y
prefix f() suffix
done
prefix g() suffix
prefix h() suffix
```

Comment: True, but the * operator can be overloaded, and in the case of an STL iterator,  either way you dereference it uses an operator overload.

Comment: @DanKorn `operator*` is not applied recursively to its return value, unlike `operator->`.